# I don't get push notifications from google drive api

Tags: java, push-notification, google-drive-api, drive

I followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push#receiving-notifications)

For local testing and webhook processing, I used https://webhook.site
I managed to get messages about file changes (google sheets)

Next, I tried to configure the local endpoint of my application to handle the webhook
From the documentation https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7072069?hl=en

> An address property string set to the URL that listens and responds to
> notifications for this notification channel. This is your Webhook
> callback URL, and it must use HTTPS.

Also for local testing I used https://ngrok.com/ [image]

```
  @PostMapping("/notifications")
  @AnonymousAllowed
  public ResponseEntity<Void> webHookHandler(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String headerGoogChanged = request.getHeader("x-goog-changed");
    if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(headerGoogChanged) && headerGoogChanged.contains("content")) {
      service.parseDashboardAndSave(view.getGrid(), sheetsService.readSheetValuesBatch());
      sheetsService.writeSheetValuesBatch(service.getKeyWordDashboards());
      log.info("Push notification processed: {}", request);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
```

But I don't get push notifications

At the same time, calling endpoints https://localhost:8080/notifications and https://xxxxxxeu.ngrok.io/notifications through postman will work

I heard that you need to pass domain verification and also have an SSL certificate
I found that now there is no need to confirm the domain in this [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7072069?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

i tried to get changes with these [changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/changes) api after creating webhook with `watch` method and this worked for me, its all about pagetoken which used to track the changes.

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.